# How can I update my gcc 6.3.0 to gcc 7.1.0 in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++, ubuntu-17.04

Is there any ppa available for gcc 7.1 for ubuntu 17.04?

https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.1
This ppa is for 16.04, which I have found

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this page [ubuntu-toolchain-r/test](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test)

You can install using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-7
```

I think ubuntu stopped putting the minor version as part of the package name.

Comment: Latest version of gcc 7.1 is released in May, but this ppa is older unstable version, I guess.